# I can't get max and min from my table

Tags: sql, database, firebird

How come this query returns an error?

```
select CUSTOMER, TOTAL_VALUE
from CUSTOMER, SALES
where TOTAL_VALUE in (select max(TOTAL_VALUE), min(TOTAL_VALUE)
from SALES)
```

When I just do max(TOTAL_VALUE) or min(TOTAL_VALUE) alone it works perfectly. But I need to get the min number in TOTAL_VALUE and max number in TOTAL_VALUE. Can anyone help me figure out why this query won't work for me? I would like to keep the structure that i have (using the in operator and nested subquery)

Comment: If it *returns an error*, you have that *error* right in front of you on your screen. There is absolutely no reason for you not to include it in your post so that we can see it too. You're asking us to help you solve your problem; the very least you can do is provide the information you already have right in front of you for us to use to do so.

Comment: Sorry if i offended you. I tried to get as much info as I could. The error is a page long and I can't copy and paste since I'm in a vm. I didn't mean to get so many down votes. I just was confused on the syntax of my query. Sorry. Will try better next time...

Answer (score 1):

It returns an error because the subquery is returning two values, not one.  Here is one fix:

```
select CUSTOMER, TOTAL_VALUE
from CUSTOMER cross join
     SALES join
     (select max(TOTAL_VALUE) as maxt, min(TOTAL_VALUE) as mint
      from sales
     ) sm 
     where s.total_value in (sm.maxt, sm.mint);
```

That said, the query makes no sense.  There you are going to get a list of every customer along with the value of the overall minimum and maximum sales.

This does answer your question.  If you have another question, then provide sample data, desired results, in *another* question.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of info. I did not mean to get so many down votes.. I am working in a vm and I couldn't get the copy and paste to work to copy over all of the info with the problem. Thanks for the help and mature answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Joining SALES and CUSTOMER tables):

```
select C.CUSTOMER, MIN(TOTAL_VALUE), MAX(TOTAL_VALUE)
from SALES S
join CUSTOMER C on S.Customer_ID=C.Customer_ID
group by C.CUSTOMER
order by C.CUSTOMER
```

Comment: unfortunately, customer is only in the Customer table. They do share a primary key of customer_id